# Facing several errors using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-run

I first tried installing React using `create-react-app`, and at that time, it showed me some warnings. I ignored them at that time and started working on my project. Then, recently I tried to deploy my react app to github pages, and was facing errors again!

First, I got:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
^


MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
```

I used this: `npm i -D --save-exact mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.5` to change the version and got away with the error, but when running `npm run deploy` again, I got this error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use 
external type 'module' within a script
```

I don't understand what this really means and it also doesn't show any line reference from which the error was causing.

Well, after that, I thought that something was wrong with my project and tried to start another react project.
I used `npx create-react-app react-deploy` to see if this app would deploy to github pages. But, it didn't install and showed me this:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZAS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-02T08_01_49_556Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts 
  cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test-deploy/ from C:\Users\ZAS\Desktop\Web\React Start\react-deploy
Done.
```

I'm farely new to React and Node.js/npm and now, I'm really frustrated due to all of these errors.
My node version is `16.13.0` and npm's: `8.1.0`

Should I install the older version of node from scratch or not?

Comment: What makes you think an *older* version is the answer?

Comment: I searched the internet and someone was facing the same error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading isServer), and there, that person installed the older version of node

Comment: Should I re-install node and react?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241635/discussion-between-m-abdullah-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: `npx create-react-app react-deploy` tries to create a new app called `react-deploy`, so you wouldn't want to do that. What was your original `npx create-react-app` command that you used to start this? *(I don't believe in hiding comments off in the chat when they're directly relevant to the question.)*

Comment: I wanted to make another app just to see if I can deploy that to github pages, that's why I ran that npx create-react-app command but it wouldn't install

Comment: Gotcha. I'm afraid I don't know what's wrong. I just did `npx create-react-app basic-react-app` using Node v16.13.2 and `npm` 8.1.2 and didn't run into any trouble. Completely uninstalling and reinstalling might help, or might not. :-| Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I'll try,

Thanks!